# Using tinyint as datatype in MySQL 5.5.57

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble with the following SQL query. The error arises in status field when I specify tinyint as its data-type. Am I using the wrong syntax?

**Query**

```
create table device_master( 
id INT,
serial_number VARCHAR, 
status TINYINT, 
created_at DATETIME, 
updated_at TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP, 
created_by INT, 
updated_by INT, primary key(id));
```

**Error**

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' status TINYINT, created_at DATETIME, updated_at TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT TIM' at line 1

Comment: Don't use the `sql-server` tag for `mysql` questions.

Comment: Oops..!! Sorry, My bad..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two syntax errors

1. You have to specify the max length of the varchar e.g. `VARCHAR(255)`
2. Its `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (note the _)

Try running:

```
create table device_master( 
  id INT,
  serial_number VARCHAR(255), 
  status TINYINT, 
  created_at DATETIME, 
  updated_at TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  created_by INT, 
  updated_by INT, 
  primary key(id)
);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm..!! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think not tinyint is your problem. You have to declare the length of varchar for serial_number:

```
create table device_master( 
id INT,
serial_number VARCHAR(100), 
status TINYINT, 
created_at DATETIME, 
updated_at TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
created_by INT, 
updated_by INT, primary key(id));
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the issue is that you did not specify length for `serial_number` field. It should be defined as `serial_number VARCHAR(N),`, where N is the maximum length in characters.

Note, that the code excerpt in the syntax error message start **before** the word `status`, indicating the error occurred way before the `tinyint` data type were specified.